# Add Connection Points doesn't generate fire_* methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, atl

I'm trying to create callback function on ATL project in Visual Studio 2019. When I use "Add Connection Point", Visual Studio (2017 and 2019) does not generate fire_* methods in CProxy_*Events.

Please help solve this problem.

Comment: Needs more details. VS is still capable to generate those like in good old days. Does it at all get you any output? Also if you are trying to get that from embedded IDL, you might want to try out a type library already built from your code.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionPoint bug is old Visual Studio bug. I show my Fire_* method. Insert it into your CProxy_* class:

```
HRESULT Fire_On/*event_name*/(/*args list*/) 
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    T* pThis = static_cast<T*>(this);
    int cConnections = m_vec.GetSize();
    for (int iConnection = 0; iConnection < cConnections; iConnection++)
    {
        pThis->Lock();
        CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(iConnection);
        pThis->Unlock();
        IDispatch* pConnection = static_cast<IDispatch*>(punkConnection.p);

        if (pConnection) 
        {
            CComVariant avarParams[/*count of args list*/];
            avarParams[0] = /*arg from args list*/;
            avarParams[1] = /*arg from args list*/;
            /*other params*/
            avarParams[/*N-1*/] = /*arg from args list*/;
            DISPPARAMS params = { avarParams, nullptr, /*count of args list*/, 0 };
            hr = pConnection->Invoke(/*number of function*/, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, 
                nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```